# touchesEnded with addGesture

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, c4

I am trying to get touchesEnded to fire after a gesture. I've included a code snippet where both touchesBegan and touchesEnded are enabled to fire. I get two odd behaviours with the code below. When I pan it prints begin and swiped ended. When I touch the canvas I get a begin and two end messages.

I've tried removing the touchesBegan to be sure it doesn't conflict with touchesEnded but the behaviour is the same.

```
#import "C4WorkSpace.h"

@implementation C4WorkSpace

-(void)setup
{
    [self addGesture:PAN name:@"pan" action:@"bbb:"];
    [self gestureForName:@"pan"].delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
    [self gestureForName:@"pan"].delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
}

-(void) bbb : (UIGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        C4Log(@"Swipe Ended");
}
-(void) touchesBegan
{
    C4Log(@"Begin");
}
-(void) touchesEnded
{
    C4Log(@"End");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue that deals directly with the way that UIGestures are architected to work. The `delaysTouchesEnded` basically **delays** the sending of a message to `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and setting this value to `NO` doesn't necessarily mean that the event will be triggered.

From the docs:

> If the gesture recognizer subsequently recognizes its gesture, these
>   touch objects are cancelled (via a touchesCancelled:withEvent:
>   message). If the gesture recognizer does not recognize its gesture,
>   the window delivers these objects in an invocation of the view’s
>   touchesEnded:withEvent: method. Set this property to NO to have touch
>   objects in the UITouchPhaseEnded delivered to the view while the
>   gesture recognizer is analyzing the same touches.

In your code snippet the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` are NOT actually enabled to fire. What is happening is you're disabling the "delay" on whether or not the gesture will *allow* the `touchesBegan` or `touchesEnded` to be available for firing.

With `delaysTouchesBegan` set to NO, the following happens:

1. touch happens
2. gesture intercepts
3. gesture is recognized
4. `touchesBegan` actually happened (because the gesture recognized)
5. no delay, `touchesBegan` fires

With `delaysTouchesEnded` the firing of `touchesEnded` is contingent on whether or not the gesture successfully completes... Unlike the previous case where `touchesBegan` always actually happens at the beginning of the gesture.

What happens in this case is the following:

1. gesture is being recognized
2. gesture completes successfully
3. gesture CANCELS touches for the view in which the gesture happens (this is expected behaviour of `UIGestureRecognizer`

... `touchesEnded` happens when:

1. gesture is being recognized
2. gesture completes UNSUCCESSFULLY
3. `touchesEnded` is fired

With your code if you touch down, hold the gesture without moving your finger, and then release after a little while the `touchesEnded` gets fired. The reason is that the `PAN` doesn't complete successfully and allows the `touchesEnded` to fire.

### A different approach

You are working with a gesture, so any interaction you want to have happen should take into consideration the gesture you're working with... That is, when you start working with a gesture try and think in terms of the **gesture**, knowing that it is going to come between the view you're touching and its inherent `touchesBegan`, etc., methods.

### Bottom Line

**Your `bbb:` method is perfect.**

When working with gestures, pipe through a method like this to determine the various states of the gesture. *This is how you want to work with gestures.*

Try the following code:

```
#import "C4WorkSpace.h"

@implementation C4WorkSpace
-(void)setup
{
    [self addGesture:PAN name:@"pan" action:@"bbb:"];
    [self gestureForName:@"pan"].delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
    [self gestureForName:@"pan"].delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
}

-(void) bbb : (UIGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        C4Log(@"PAN Begin");
    }
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        C4Log(@"PAN ended");
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan {
    C4Log(@"A touch began");
}

-(void)touchesEnded {
    C4Log(@"A touch ended");
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    C4Log(@"A touch cancelled");
}

@end
```

Notice that the `TOUCH` event gets cancelled after you `BEGIN` the gesture? This is why `touchesEnded` will never be fired, because when the GESTURE begins the system recognizes that the "touch" isn't really a touch and is really a gesture.